# snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it

Tags: apt, snap

I try to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` and I get the following output:

```
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.32.8+18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.32.8+18.04) ...
Setting up snapd (2.32.8+18.04) ...
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
```

This just hangs here, I've tried running it for over an hour now and nothing. It means I can't install anything at all, all other packages seem to work fine.

I have also tried purging snap and then reinstalling it but I just end up back where I was.